# SPRESENSEのarduino版で録音とLTE送信を同時にしたい（録音がエラーストップになります）

Tags: c++, spresense, arduino, マルチスレッド

Spresense（arduino版）にて、現在録音とデータ送信を同時に行いたく、実装を進めております。
マルチスレッド化はpthreadを用いて実装をしておりますが、録音のエラーでストップしてしまいます。
原因や解決策お分かりの方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

使用
・SPRESENSE　メインボード
・SPRESENSE　LTE拡張ボード
・pthread (nuttx)
・message queue

コード抜粋

スレッド作成

```
void * thread_LTE(void *data) {
    Serial.println("LTE_pthread");

    while(true){
        Serial.println("LTE_LOOP");
        String sendFileName;
        sendFileName = recvQueue();
        if (!sendFileName == ""){
            Serial.println("START LTE SEND");
            Serial.println(sendFileName);
            sendDataAws(sendFileName);
            sendFileName = "";
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

void * thread_rec(void *data) {
    Serial.println("rec_pthread");
    startMP3Recording(Filename);
    return NULL;
}



int recLTE_pthread() {
    pthread_t th;
    void *th_ret;
    
    if (pthread_create(&th, NULL, thread_rec, (void *)100) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create");
    return 1;
    }
    
    if (pthread_create(&th, NULL, thread_LTE, (void *)100) != 0) {
        perror("pthread_create");
        return 1;
    }

    Serial.println("Thread  was made");

    if (pthread_join(th, &th_ret) != 0) {
        perror("pthread_join");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

message queue

```
String recvQueue (){
    const char* que_name = "/recEnd";
    struct mq_attr attr;
    mqd_t q;
    char* buf;
    String fileName = "";
    enum abc{O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, O_RDWR, O_CREAT, O_EXCL, O_NONBLOC};

    q = mq_open(que_name, O_RDONLY);
    mq_getattr( q ,&attr );
    buf = (char *)malloc(attr.mq_msgsize);
    mq_receive( q, (char*)buf, attr.mq_msgsize, NULL);

    Serial.println(fileName);
    fileName = String(buf);

    free(buf);
    mq_close(q);

    return fileName;
}

void sendQueue (char* fileName){
    const char* que_name = "/recEnd";
    struct mq_attr attr;
    mqd_t q;
    char* buf = fileName;
    enum abc{O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, O_RDWR, O_CREAT, O_EXCL, O_NONBLOC};

    q =  q = mq_open(que_name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, NULL);
    mq_send( q, (const char *)(&buf) , sizeof(buf) , 0);
    Serial.println("rec data stocked");
    mq_close(q);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

以上の問題は確定できませんが、予感があります。

pthreadはいくつかのリソースを共通しています。pthread_createをtask_createに書き換え、試してみるのはいかがでしょうか？

NuttXのドキュメンテーションの参照先
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTTX/Tasks+vs.+Threads+FAQ

> If a task group receives a signal and more than one thread is waiting on that signal, then one and only one indeterminate thread out of that waiting group will receive the signal.

> Here is the definitive list of what is shared. Most of these resources reside within the task group structure struct task_group_s:
>
> - Child task exit status
> - Pthread join data
> - Environment variables
> - File descriptors
> - FILE streams
> - Sockets
> - Opened message queues
> - pthread keys
> - Support data for atexit(), on_exit, and/or waitpid()

具体的なエラー番号やメッセージを追加すると助かります。